# Integer overflow in operations

Tags: c++, x86, x86-64, integer-overflow

Following code:

```
UINT32 dword = 4294967295;

if(dword + 1 != 0) // condition
```

In such operations is there any warranty that the biggest (whole) register (avaiable on architecture) is always used? and above condition will be always true on 64 bit mode, while false for 32 bit mode?

Comment: I believe the standard states what happens with integer overflow, although I can't remember the specifics. Of course `UINT32` will be the same size on both 32 and 64 bit architectures so you'd expect it to act the same.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Unsigned overflow wraps. Signed overflow has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'll depend on what sort of type `UINT32` really is.

If it's an unsigned type (as you'd expect) then results are guaranteed to be reduced modulo the largest value that can be represented + 1, so code like this:

```
if (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_unsigned)
    assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()+1==0);
```

...should succeed. OTOH, based on the name, we'd typically expect that to be a 32-bit type regardless of the implementation, register size, etc., so we'd expect to get the same result regardless.

Edit: [sorry, had to stop and feed baby for a few minutes] I should add in more detail. Although we can certainly hope it's unlikely in practice, it's conceivable that `UINT32` could really be (say) a 16-bit `unsigned short`. For the sake of discussion, let's assume that `int` is 32 bits.

In this case, `dword+1` would involve math between an `unsigned short` and an `int` (the implicit type of `1`). In that case, `dword` would actually be initialized to 65535. Then, when you did the addition, that `65535` would be promoted to a 32-bit `int`, and `1` added as an `int`, so the result would be 65536.

At least in theory, the same basic thing could happen if UINT32 was an unsigned 32-bit type (as we'd expect) but `int` was a 64-bit type. Again, `dword` would be promoted to `int` before doing the math, so the math would be done on 64-bit quantities rather than 32-bit, so (again) the result would not wrap around to 0.

Comment: Using `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_unisgned` makes my code smell purple :P

Comment: "reduced modulo the largest value that can be represented" *plus one*

Comment: For language-lawyer points: if `UINT32` is a 32 bit `unsigned short`, and `int` is signed 33 bit, then the code has undefined behavior. Woo!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hey, it's late in the day... got to use a bit of humor to keep going.

Comment: @NikBougalis: No problem at all -- I'm slow, but it made me smile when I finally realized...